# Error when deploying my UWP app

Tags: windows, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

When I try to run my app in Visual Studio 2015, the following errors occur:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error      Error : DEP6100 :
>   The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage
>   'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.':
>
> SEHException - External component has thrown an
>   exception.    TestFirstUWA         Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error     Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot
>   be found. TestFirstUWA

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try running `net start IpOverUsbSvc` in an elevated command prompt. If that doesn't work, try plugging your device into other USB ports.

Comment: Reinstall the latest SDK. This can happen if you install an old SDK on top of a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 has solved the problem in my case.
(Because it contains the Windows 10 SDK Version 1511 (comment from Raymond Chen)).

- Device: Windows 10 Mobile, Version 10.0.10586.11
- Development-System: Windows 10 Version 1511 (Build 10586.0)